# How to return all records from all tables?

Tags: sql, database, join

for a school assignment, I have to write a query where I need to join all the tables in a database.
The database looks as following:

[Screenshot](http://cl.ly/image/1702412I3I2e)

So the query needs to join all the tables and show all the records.
I'm trying to do this, but for the past few days it didn't work.
Can anyone help me?

What I tried:

```
SELECT *
FROM gebruiker G,
    gebruiker G2 gebruikertype GT,
    aankoop A,
    trackaankoop TA,
    track T,
    genre GE
WHERE G.idGebruikertype = GT.idGebruikertype
    AND G.idGebruiker = A.idGebruiker
    AND A.idAankoop = TA.idAankoop
    AND TA.idTrack = T.idTrack
    AND T.idGebruiker = G2.idGebruiker
    AND T.idGenre = GE.idGenre.
```

Comment: You need to show your code, people are not just going to write the query for you, but they will be happy to help fix what you've done so far. Just remember, it's easy to join table A to table B (when there's an established relationship) but you need to specify which columns the query should use to check for equality.

Comment: Did your teacher really ask you to join every table and return all variables? This is a weird assignment. Maybe you can show us what "didn't work"?

Comment: I tried it like this: select *
 from gebruiker G,gebruiker G2 gebruikertype GT, aankoop A, trackaankoop TA,  track T, genre GE
where G.idGebruikertype = GT.idGebruikertype
and G.idGebruiker = A.idGebruiker
and A.idAankoop = TA.idAankoop
and TA.idTrack = T.idTrack
and T.idGebruiker = G2.idGebruiker
and T.idGenre = GE.idGenre.

Comment: Just to clarify: gebruiker G1 means the artist of the track

Comment: Can you share the exact wording of the assignment?

Comment: It says: join all the following tables. I know it's not much, but it's what we got. And when I asked for more details, the teacher said we just needed to join everything.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you have to show all rows of all tables using a JOIN, then you would need a `FULL JOIN` to display the records.

```
SELECT *
FROM gebruiker G 
    FULL JOIN gebruikertype GT ON G.idGebruikertype = GT.idGebruikertype
    FULL JOIN aankoop A ON G.idGebruiker = A.idGebruiker
    FULL JOIN trackaankoop TA ON A.idAankoop = TA.idAankoop
    FULL JOIN track T ON TA.idTrack = T.idTrack
    FULL JOIN gebruiker G2 ON T.idGebruiker = G2.idGebruiker
    FULL JOIN genre GE ON T.idGenre = GE.idGenre
```

The type of JOIN you were recreating with the WHERE clauses was an `INNER JOIN` where only the records that have correspondents in all the tables are displayed.

Comment: When I do this, I get errors on the full join. However, when I replace full join by left join, it gives me all the users(gebruikers), their details, usertype(gebruikerstype). It also shows the trackaankoopID, but this has to be linked to tracks, which need to be shown to. How can I solve this?

Comment: Ignore my other comment :) I just check the database and the 'trackaankoop' table appears empty . I added a record and it worked. Thank you for your help!

Answer (score 0):

Assuming Gebruiker is the main table you could use the following to join

```
 SELECT G.*, R.*, GT.*, T.*, TG.*, A.*, C.*, TA.*
   FROM gebruiker AS G
        JOIN gebruikertype as GT ON GT.idGebruikerType = G.idGebruikerType
        JOIN review AS R ON R.idGebruiker = G.idGebruiker
        JOIN track AS T ON T.idGebruiker = G.idGebruiker
             JOIN genre as TG ON TG.idGenre = T.idGenre
        JOIN aankoop AS A ON A.idGebruiker = G.idGebruiker
             JOIN creditaankoop AS C ON C.idAankoop = A.idAankoop
             JOIN trackaankoop as TA ON TA.idAankoop = A.idAankoop
```

`SELECT G.*, R.*, GT.*, T.*, TG.*, A.*, C.*, TA.*` can be replaced with `SELECT *`

Review can join to either the Gebruiker table:

```
 SELECT G.*, R.*
   FROM gebruiker AS G
        JOIN review AS R ON R.idGebruiker = G.idGebruiker
```

or the Track table:

```
 SELECT T.*, R.*
   FROM track AS T
        JOIN review AS R ON R.idTrack = T.idTrack
```

Similarly, the TrackAankoop table can join to the Aankoop table:

```
 SELECT G.*, A.*, TA.*
   FROM gebruiker AS G
        JOIN aankoop AS A ON A.idGebruiker = G.idGebruiker
             JOIN trackaankoop AS TA ON TA.idAankoop = A.idAankoop
```

or the Track table;

```
 SELECT T.*, TA.*
   FROM track AS T
        JOIN trackaankoop AS TA ON TA.idTrack = T.idTrack
```